# Disable GPO denies domain admins login

Tags: windows, group-policy, domain

A GPO was created and linked to top level that denies login to domain admins.  No other accounts are able to log into domain controllers.

Is there a way to change this policy or somehow recover?

Right now I am faced with a large domain that is basically unmanageable since I have no way to log into DCs. DCs are *Windows 2008r2* and clients are *Windows 7*. I can still log in to client machines. I do have puppet on the DCs and access to the puppet master.

Comment: You can boot into domain recovery mode.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the GPMC, (Group Policy Management Console) opened with the domain admin rights.

Or with powershell, you can use these commands always with a console opened with domain admin rights:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/Library/ee461027.aspx
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/fr-FR/4035feb6-38df-4aab-ad8a-76fe48d98adc/how-to-modify-group-policy-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell

Hopefully, your GPO has blocked the interactive sessions and could use these two solutions.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the problem GPO. You can do it with an LDAP client. This can be done even if you cannot login as domain admin on a domain computer:

1. Run LDAP client (I suggest ADSI Edit). Connect to your DC and bind as Domain Admin (your policy can't block an LDAP bind). You can run *ADSI Edit*  as any user, even from a computer outside of the domain, but when you select the connection settings in the dialogue under the "Advanced..." button you must provide domain administrator credentials. [More read about using *ADSI Edit* here.]
2. Find your problem GPO ID: Browse with LDAP `CN=Policies,CN=System` in domain root and search for the Policy ID by **displayName** attribute (not an easy task when you have many policies).
3. Once you find the policy in `CN=Policies,CN=System` set its **flag** attribute to `3` - [which means GPO disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh455118.aspx).
4. Wait for group policy to refresh (or reboot).

Comment: How do I do LDAP bind? The other solutions are not working as we seem to have policies preventing the gpmc on client machines and the powershell gpo module isn't functioning

Comment: @CW33 You can run *ADSIedit*  from any user, even from a computer outside of the domain, but when you select the connection settings in the dialogue under the "Advanced..." button must be set domain administrator credentials. [More read about *ADSIedit* using here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to log in to a domain controller to manage group policy. You can install the Remote Server Administration Tools on a Windows 7 PC. These are the same tools that are installed on a Windows server when you enable a feature.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Make sure you read the install instructions because just double-clicking the file will not install the tools.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we were not able to make any of these things work in our situation. Other policies prevented some of it and the binding as domain credentials did not work for us either. Our solution was to use puppet, which runs as a service account to execute a secedit command and override the poorly set GPO. Thanks though for everyones help.